# kubernetes rbac authorization layer seems to give incorrect result

Tags: kubernetes

Am trying to better understand RBAC in kubernetes. Came across this unexpected situation where authorization test using `kubectl auth can-i` and actual results are different. In short, newly created user should not be able to get pods as per this test, however this user can actually get pods.

Version:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.1", GitCommit:"b1b29978270dc22fecc592ac55d903350454310a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-07-17T18:53:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.1", GitCommit:"b1b29978270dc22fecc592ac55d903350454310a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-07-17T18:43:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

kubectl config for user in questions:

```
$ kubectl config view --minify
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/master/ca.pem
    server: https://192.168.1.111:6443
  name: jdoe
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: jdoe
    user: jdoe
  name: jdoe
current-context: jdoe
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: jdoe
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/master/jdoe.pem
    client-key: /home/master/jdoe-key.pem
```

The test against authorization layer says jdoe cannot get pods.

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get pods --as jdoe
no
```

However, jdoe can get pods:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress-controller-87554c57b-ttgwp   1/1       Running   0          5h
kube-system     coredns-5f7d467445-ngnvf                   1/1       Running   0          1h
kube-system     coredns-5f7d467445-wwf5s                   1/1       Running   0          5h
kube-system     weave-net-25kq2                            2/2       Running   0          5h
kube-system     weave-net-5njbh                            2/2       Running   0          4h
```

Got similar results from auth layer after switching back to admin context:

```
$ kubectl config use-context kubernetes
Switched to context "kubernetes".
$ kubectl config view --minify
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://192.168.1.111:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: admin
  name: kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/master/admin.pem
    client-key: /home/master/admin-key.pem
```

From here too, user jdoe is not supposed to get pods.

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get pods --as jdoe
no
```

Output of `kubectl config view`

```
$ kubectl config view 
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/master/ca.pem
    server: https://192.168.1.111:6443
  name: jdoe
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://192.168.1.111:6443
  name: kubernetes
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/master/ca.pem
    server: https://192.168.1.111:6443
  name: master
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: jdoe
    user: jdoe
  name: jdoe
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: admin
  name: kubernetes
- context:
    cluster: master
    user: master
  name: master
current-context: kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/master/admin.pem
    client-key: /home/master/admin-key.pem
- name: jdoe
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/master/jdoe.pem
    client-key: /home/master/jdoe-key.pem
- name: master
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/master/master.pem
    client-key: /home/master/master-key.pem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl get pods` with no specific pod name actually does a list. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb for details about what verb corresponds to a given request.

What does `can-i list pods` return?

Comment: Got `no` for `kubectl auth can-i list pods --as jdoe` ... I get your point.

Comment: --as uses impersonation to make the authz check, and makes it impersonating the specified username. Impersonation has no knowledge of any group memberships associated with the user unless you specify those with --as-group, so it is possible the jdoe.pem client certificate contains group memberships that are responsible for the `get pods` invocation succeeding, but aren't considered in the `can-I` invocation. What does `openssl x509 -in /home/master/jdoe.pem -text -noout` show as the client certificate subject?

Comment: it shows `Subject: C=IN, L=BGLR, O=system:masters, OU=CKA, CN=jdoe`

Comment: `O=system:masters` adds the super user group to that credential. That group is authorized to do anything. `can-i --as=jdoe --as-group=system:masters ...` will always report `yes`